# Make a Raspberry Pi reliable on remote place

Tags: wifi, connection

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a mobile router at a remote place and host a server which I can access. The problem is this setup is not really reliable. Every 2 days there is like a problem, like the Raspberry Pi not responding anymore or refusing any connection, just randomly shutting off and so on.

Which tricks do you guys use to make a Raspberry Pi reliable to stay on for days without any problems?

Also I have set up a script to monitor if wlan is connected and if not write iwconfig to a file and restart wlan0. Seems not to happen often, atleast not as frequent as the total connecting problems I have

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said in the comments section of Dwebtron's answer, your problem is definitely the power supply.

For one thing, your power supply is definitely on the weak side.  It's generally recommended that your power supply be able to handle at least 1A. 700mA might power the device, but adding a wifi dongle, and overclocking the RPi would certainly strain it. Your 1A version will definitely help.

Secondly, an intermittent power-supply is definitely not a good thing.  If the power supply dips enough that the lights are flickering, it's probably dipping enough that the RPi shuts down, or misbehaves unpredictably.  This can lead to anything from software/kernel glitches to a corrupted file system.

I would recommend an uninterruptable power supply.  Something like an [external battery backup](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N2T7U90) could help with that and not cost a fortune.

Comment: I will definitely switch psu and maybe also add a battery backup pack and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that a lot of problems with my Pi being unreliable have to do with the memory card used. Samsung's seems to work like crap, and the SanDisks I have can stay on for weeks / months (so far).

Comment: I am using a SanDisk right now, so that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Do you have multiple pis to try? Maybe that one has some bad RAM or something. Have you tried memtest or another pi in that location? Have you tried this pi in a known-good location?

Comment: No I don't. I don't think it it a manufacturing problem as it works totally fine, just the problem is it gets disconnected from the network, nging refuses the connection (or the pi) and so on. It is not a hardware problem I think

Comment: When it's been 'disconnected', have you tried to access it physically? Does it work fine then? Could it be a network/router issue? I see you have this question tagged wifi.... There could be interference nearby causing a disconnected signal, perhaps? Raspian shouldn't randomly shut itself down, and *nix systems are typically rock-solid stability-wise, so I wouldn't be looking into software.... Unless you've messed with it ;)

Comment: Yeah I did, sometimes I get connection refused when I'm in the same network like the raspi via wlan or even eth0, or I get host is down sometimes too. Also there is not a single wifi signal in a 200m radius to the raspi so that's not the problem

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but I also remember hearing something about the pis having issues with interference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=12244&p=131348 I'm not sure if it's the problem you are having, but it's something worth considering IMO

Comment: Have you tried plugging a keyboard/mouse/monitor into it when it is refusing connections? Does that still work?

Comment: No I haven't actually. I might try that as soon as I have time and it happens to not being accessable. Also bringing a monitor to such a remote place might be a problem and a bit akward :P

Comment: Also I removed all the gui packages from the raspi following a tutorial on the internet so I only have the terminal left

Comment: Ahh. I'm betting that if you were to try to access it with a keyboard + mouse you probably won't get it to respond. We'll see, I suppose :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll see. Also one thing that popped into my mind is that the power source (230V AC) is kinda unstable and domestic lights flicker like once every hour or so. The power adapter is also an old samsung one (5V 700mA). Could the power flickering or the bad power supply be the problem? I might try to switch power supply and use a better samsung 5V 1A one

Comment: Oh and I overclocked the pi to 800mhz, so I will turn down the clock rate to 700mhz. I guess overclocking and 24/7 don't go together that well

Comment: It could be. Do remember, these are $25-35 machines haha I actually work with quite a bit of them, and sitting on my desk now are 5 memory cards that I know will not work reliably for more than 1 hour (God knows why, they work everywhere else), a pi that refuses to boot past it's BIOS, a pi who's wifi card randomly disconnects from it's router, and a pi who's wifi card occasionally never shows itself to the OS. These things can be temperamental. :/

Comment: Yeah I know the struggle. There are also quite alot of things connected to it, like a WiFi adapter, 4 temperature sensors, a humidity and a barometer one and a rain sensor.

Comment: Maybe one of them is the problem